# Spring Integration manually start/stop channel adapter via control bus

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is there anyway to manually start/init a channel adapter?

I have two pairs of inbound/outbound adapters in my context.xml and would like to decide at runtime which one of them I want to get started.

EDIT:

The concrete scenario:
I have a client, that can be configured at runtime to be an mqtt publisher or subscriber.
My context.xml looks like this:

```
<int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter 
    client-id="foo"
    auto-startup="true"
    url="tcp://192.168.97.164:1883"
    topics="testtopic/#"
    channel="writeToFile" />

<file:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="writeToFile"
    auto-startup="true"
    directory="./test/out"
    delete-source-files="false"/>

<int:transformer id="Transformer"
    ref="MessageTransformer"
    input-channel="readFromFile"
    output-channel="mqttOut"
    method="bytesFromFile" />

<bean id="MessageTransformer" class="MessageTransformer"/>

<int-mqtt:outbound-channel-adapter 
    id="mqttOut"
    client-id="foo"
    url="tcp://192.168.97.164:1883"
    auto-startup="false"
    default-qos="1"
    default-retained="true"
    default-topic="testtopic/bla"
    />

    <file:inbound-channel-adapter
    auto-startup="false" 
    id="readFromFile"
    directory="./test/in"
    filename-pattern="myFile*">
    <int:poller id="poller"
        fixed-rate="5000" />     
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

As you can see, I have two settings:
1. Subscriber case: Read mqtt message -> Write to file
2. Publisher case: Poll a file from directory -> Send via mqtt

I decide at runtime what setting is to be applied.

So can you kindly tell me how this control-bus thing would fit here exactly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set `autoStartup="false"` and either directly `start()`/`stop()` them, or use a `<control-bus/>` (send `@myAdapter.start()`).

Getting a direct reference (autowire etc), depends on the endpoint type. If it's a polled endpoint, inject a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`; message-driven adapters vary, but generally are a `MessageProducerSupport` or `MessagingGatewaySupport`.

EDIT:

Read about the [control-bus here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#control-bus).

Give the inbound adapter an `id` attribute.

Add `<control-bus input-channel="control"/>`

Add `<int:gateway service-interface="foo.Controller" default-request-channel="control"/>`

Create a gateway interface

```
public interface Controller {

    void control(String command);

}
```

`@Autowire` the gateway (or use `context.getBean(Controller.class)`).

Then, when you are ready to start the adapter, call, e.g. `gateway.control("@mqttOut.start()")`.

You don't need `auto-startup="false"` on the outbound adapters.

However, for a simple use case like this, you might want to investigate using Spring profiles instead (put the adapters in a profile and enable the profile at runtime.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I am afraid, I still need some further assistance with the control bus. I therefore just updated the question.

Comment: I added details for how to use the control bus for this scenario. But you might want to look at Spring profiles instead.

Comment: Thank you. This works fine for the first case (starting the mqqt:message-driven-channel-adapter), but when I try '@readFromFile.start()' I get the following error: The method 'start' is not supported by this command processor. If using the Control Bus, consider adding '@ManagedOperation' or '@ManagedAttribute'.

Comment: It's because you are using implicit channel naming on the inbound adapter; when you don't give the channel adapter a `channel` attribute, the channel gets the id `readFromFile` and the adapter is called `readFromFile.adapter`. You are trying to start() the channel, which is not allowed. So, either use explicit id and channel on the adapter, or use `@'readFromFile.adapter'.start()`.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to go with the Spring profiles for now. Great tip. Still I have one question: Where exactly is the link between the gateway/control-bus and my inbound-adapter? I admit, it is working, but still I cannot figure out how!

Comment: The bean name `@adapterId.start()`.

Comment: "The Control Bus has an input channel that can be accessed for invoking operations on the beans in the application context." From the docs... I am so blind... Thanx again Gary...

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, you need to first set the channel-adapter auto-startup property to false `auto-startup="false"` and then using control bus start/stop the adapter

See here control bus example - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/control-bus

Comment: Thank you guys, but I am afraid, I still need some further assistance with the control bus. I therefore just updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for same example using spring integration Java DSL, but haven't found anything, so I've created my own. It shows to be pretty simple to configure.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow controlBus() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(controlChannel())
            .controlBus()
            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel controlChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}
```

To Stop it:

`controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@myInboundAdapter.stop()"));`

https://github.com/CauchyPeano/sftp-poller-control-bus