# Accessing Spring bean from different HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I now know how to manually start and stop a channel adapter thanks to Gary Russells answer to my previous question on SO: [Spring Integration manually start/stop channel adapter via control bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915524/spring-integration-manually-start-stop-channel-adapter-via-control-bus)

My application is now running as a servlet on a tomcat. Now, is there anyway to stop a channel from a request other than the request that started this channel? I am not sure about the scope issue, but it seemes to me, like if each request is creating a new gateway, and therefore me issuing a "stop" command from a later request, would only stop a new instance, that had never been started in the first place. Or am I wrong?

My objective is to create a restful web service, which exposes endpoints to publish / subscribe / unsubscribe over MQTT, e.g.

```
http://someDomain/myModule/publishOverMQTT?topic=cloud&clientID=myClient&payload=myMsg
http://someDomain/myModule/subscribeOverMQTT&URL=someMQTTBrokerURL%clientID=myClient&topics=topic1,topic2,topic3
```

Now since this is deployed as a servlet, how is it possible to implement an "unsubscribe" request? In my understanding, unsubscribing is done in Spring Integration by stopping the channel. **!BUT! Is it possible to stop a channel from a request, other than the request that started it?**

This is my context.xml:

```
<int:control-bus input-channel="controlChannel"/>

<int:gateway
    service-interface="MyGateway"
    default-request-channel="controlChannel"/>

<int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter
    auto-startup="false"
    id="mqttInput" 
    client-id="#{controller.mqttSubscriberConfig.clientID}"
    url="#{controller.mqttSubscriberConfig.completeURL}"
    topics="#{controller.mqttSubscriberConfig.topic}"
    channel="loggingChannel" />

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" />
```

Implementing a hashmap like suggested in Gary Russells answer below, my controller now looks something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/subscribe")
public @ResponseBody void subscribe(
        @RequestParam(value="topics",   required=true) String topics,
        @RequestParam(value="clientID", required=true) String clientID,
        @RequestParam(value="url",      required=false) String url,
        @RequestParam(value="port",     required=false, defaultValue="1883") Integer port,
        HttpServletRequest request)
{
    mqttSubscriberConfig = new MQTTSubscriberConfiguration();
    mqttSubscriberConfig.setTopic(topics);
    mqttSubscriberConfig.setClientID(clientID);
    mqttSubscriberConfig.setURL(url);
    mqttSubscriberConfig.setPort(port);

    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("sub");
    ctx.load("mqtt-context.xml");
    ctx.refresh();

    ((MyGateway)ctx.getBean(MyGateway.class)).control("@mqttInput.start()");

    ctxMap.put(clientID, ctx);
}

@RequestMapping("/unsubscribe")
public @ResponseBody void unsubscribe(
        @RequestParam(value="clientID", required=true) String clientID,
        HttpServletRequest request)
{
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = ctxMap.get(clientID);
    ctx.destroy();
}
```

**STILL**, I have a strong feeling, that I should not be creating a context for each request. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no request scope for Spring Integration beans; all requests share the same Spring Integration Infrastructure.

It's not clear what you mean by "create HTTP endpoints to start/stop subscribing".

Comment: It's still not clear what you are trying to do - your URLs contain dynamic information (client id, topics etc), but your config has statically declared configuration - unless you are creating a new application context for each request and passing in the properties. If that's what you are doing, you'll need to keep each context in a map (or similar) and `destroy()` it when you get an unsubscribe request.

Comment: The idea with the map works fine. Thx, still I feel like my whole approach is messy, right? (see updated question)

Comment: If you need a different url/clientId per Http client, you have no choice but to create a new `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` each time. Whether you use an XML configuration for each, or just instantiate it in java, is your choice (you can wire the same `loggingChannel` (obtained from a common context) into multiple adapters.

Comment: BTW, you should use `ctxMap.remove()` (instead of `get()`) to avoid a memory leak.