# How to start inbound channel adapter via control bus?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to start file inbound channel adapter via control bus, but I am getting exceptions while ExpressionCommandMessageProcessor is trying to parse my command.

Here is my inbound channel adapter configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "inboundChannelAdapter")
public IntegrationFlow inputFilesReadingFlow()
{
         return IntegrationFlows
                  .from(s -> s.file(new File(inputDirectory))
                              .filter(new AcceptAllFileListFilter<File>()),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(FILE_POLLER_RATE))
                              .autoStartup(false)
                       )
                  .handle(messageProcessingService)
                  .channel(fileOutputChannel)
                  .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow()
{
    return IntegrationFlows.from("controlBusChannel").controlBus().get();
}
```

In my integration test I have autowired control bus bean:

```
@Autowired
private MessageChannel controlBusChannel;

@Test
public void testInboundChannelAdapter() 
{
    controlBusChannel.send(new GenericMessage<String>("@'inboundChannelAdapter.<property_name_placeholder>'.start()")); // ????

    // .....
}
```

So I'd like to ask how I can access 'adapter' bean(or whatever bean is responsible for the start/stop action) to initiate polling process.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the `.autoStartup(false)` you can find simple `.id()` hook.

Having that you will be able to start exactly desired `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` via ControlBus:

```
 controlBusChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@myFilePollingAdapter.start()"));
```

Your confuse that `IntegrationFlow` represents a container for its bunch of beans and doesn't allow to get access to them, because they are registered as top-level beans anyway.

Although starting with version `1.2` `StandardIntegrationFlow` is `SmartLifecycle` already, so, you really can `start/stop` all those related beans at once. Including the first File Poller one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I managed to solve it using specific id. Also I found this answer(http://stackoverflow.com/a/23916788/222002) while waiting for the reply to my question and autowiring SourcePollingChannelAdapter worked for me as well.