# How to start and stop spring file inbound adaptor using spring control bus?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I have a scenario, my application should execute the spring batch when ever I am receiving the file in the directory .. I am planning to use file inbound adaptor for that process .. Also I would like stop and start the file inbound adaptor polling using GUI.. How I can use spring control bus concept to start and stop my file inbound adaptor ?? Could you please provide some examples ?

Comment: Could you check to see if this one is the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915524/spring-integration-manually-start-stop-channel-adapter-via-control-bus

Answer (score 0):

See the [control bus sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/control-bus).

You simply send a message to the control bus with payload `adapterName.stop()`.

For a more sophisticated usage (avoid messages altogether), and using Java configuration, you can use a gateway to send messages to the control bus [see this DSL test case for an example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/file/FileTests.java#L175).