# Proper syntax to send a message to the control bus channel in an integration flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Using the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/control-bus.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269746/5873923), I set up an integration flow with an inbound JMS adapter, that I can stop/start using a control bus:

Control bus:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ControlBus {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(controlChannel()).log().controlBus().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel controlChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }
}
```

Integration flow:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor // lombok
public class Admin {
    private final MessageChannel controlChannel;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow adminFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundGateway("/admin")
                      .replyChannel("adminReply")
                      .requestMapping(r -> r.methods(DELETE, POST)))
            .route("headers.http_requestMethod", r -> r
                    .subFlowMapping(DELETE.toString(),
                        f -> f.handle((p, h) -> controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@fileInboundAdapter.stop()"))))
                    .subFlowMapping(POST.toString(),
                        f -> f.handle((p, h) -> controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@fileInboundAdapter.start()"))))
            .channel("adminReply")
            .get();
    }
}
```

It works fine, the fileInboundAdapter bean (defined in another flow) starts or stops as expected:

```
2022-10-26 17:31:01.356  INFO 11200 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=@fileInboundAdapter.stop(), headers={id=0b273024-8ca9-e383-bcfc-c487f14c044b, timestamp=1666798261355}]
2022-10-26 17:31:01.358  INFO 11200 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : stopped bean 'fileInboundAdapter'
```

But I'm curious if I can change the syntax of the router to something like :

```
.route("headers.http_requestMethod",
       r -> r.subFlowMapping(DELETE.toString(),
                             f -> f.handle((p, h) -> "@fileInboundAdapter.stop()")
                                   .channel("controlChannel"))
                    .subFlowMapping(POST.toString(),
                             f -> f.handle((p, h) -> "@fileInboundAdapter.start()")
                                   .channel("controlChannel"))
```

I've tried using the "controlChannel" name or the injected channel, to no avail, the message is sometimes passed, sometimes not, I guess I haven't properly understood the use of the channel method.

If I use the message channel name, "controlChannel", here's what I get in the log (I need 3 attempts before the bean is stopped)

```
2022-10-26 17:36:16.814  INFO 14768 --- [nio-8082-exec-2] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=@fileInboundAdapter.stop(), headers={content-length=337, http_requestMethod=DELETE, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1ea2cdcc, accept=*/*, authorization=Basic VXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQ=, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1ea2cdcc, host=localhost:8082, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8082/ldd-controller/admin, connection=keep-alive, id=909e81d5-490b-f6aa-9e59-0dc5807091c4, http_userPrincipal=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User1, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[Administrateur]], contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, user-agent=PostmanRuntime/7.29.2, timestamp=1666798576813}]
2022-10-26 17:36:48.330  INFO 14768 --- [nio-8082-exec-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=@fileInboundAdapter.stop(), headers={content-length=337, http_requestMethod=DELETE, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4d68b976, accept=*/*, authorization=Basic VXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQ=, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@4d68b976, host=localhost:8082, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8082/ldd-controller/admin, connection=keep-alive, id=d7608dc3-809d-7160-398d-f8e329d28e22, http_userPrincipal=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User1, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[Administrateur]], contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, user-agent=PostmanRuntime/7.29.2, timestamp=1666798608330}]
2022-10-26 17:36:54.957  INFO 14768 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : GenericMessage [payload=@fileInboundAdapter.stop(), headers={content-length=337, http_requestMethod=DELETE, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@7037fa6a, accept=*/*, authorization=Basic VXNlcjE6cGFzc3dvcmQ=, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@7037fa6a, host=localhost:8082, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8082/ldd-controller/admin, connection=keep-alive, id=e16b32f9-42cb-ef06-41ac-837efb8de9d9, http_userPrincipal=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=User1, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[Administrateur]], contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br, user-agent=PostmanRuntime/7.29.2, timestamp=1666798614957}]
2022-10-26 17:36:54.960  INFO 14768 --- [nio-8082-exec-4] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : stopped bean 'fileInboundAdapter'
```

On the third attempt (the one that works), I also get a "No reply received within timeout" response on the http client that send the original request.
I also need 3 requests if I want to start the bean again.

I get exactly the same result when injecting the channel.

Comment: Did you try just with `.channel(controlChannel)`? Not a name, but directly an injected one.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I did, as mentioned at the bottom of the original post, and it doesn't work either.  I added some log messages that show what happens with the version that works and the version that doesn't (at least not always...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a configuration like `f -> f.handle((p, h) -> controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@fileInboundAdapter.start()")))` you got a reply from this handler as a `true` - result of the `controlChannel.send()` call.

With the `.channel("controlChannel")` you don't get a reply because a call `fileInboundAdapter.stop()` returns `void`.

Not sure why you don't get steady results with that router, but I don't think that you are intended for a reply from there anyway.

I'd suggest to revise your configuration with a `publishSubscribeChannel(Consumer<PublishSubscribeSpec> publishSubscribeChannelConfigurer)` where one of the subscriber sub-flows would go to your router. And another would answer back to the `adminReply`. Although we need to understand what really you'd like to reply to that HTTP call:

```
      .publishSubscribeChannel(c -> c
          .subscribe(sf -> sf
                .route("headers.http_requestMethod",
                  r -> r.subFlowMapping(DELETE.toString(),
                         f -> f.handle((p, h) -> "@fileInboundAdapter.stop()")
                               .channel("controlChannel"))
                      .subFlowMapping(POST.toString(),
                         f -> f.handle((p, h) -> "@fileInboundAdapter.start()")
                               .channel("controlChannel")))
        )
      .channel("adminReply")
```

However it looks more like a plain `handle()` instead since you do not route to different channels:

```
 .handle((p, h) -> DELETE.toString().equals(h.get("http_requestMethod") ?  "@fileInboundAdapter.stop()" : "@fileInboundAdapter.start()"))
 .channel("controlChannel")
```

but still it has to be a part of publishSubscribe sub-flow since you are not going to get a reply from that control bus call.

Comment: In fact, both routes originally had a transformer to transform the `true` value received from `controlChannel.send(...)` to a "service enabled/disabled"string that was returned to the http client that sends the request. I removed it from my example to focus on the "3 attempts issue".  I indeed missed the fact that `@fileInboundAdapter.stop()` did not send a result. I'll test the `publishSubscribeChannel` to see if it fits my need, but in the end I will probably keep my original solution, since it is a bit more concise.