# Get the output from a message sent to the control bus

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I set up a control bus with Spring Integration DSL:

```
// https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/control-bus.html
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269746/5873923
@Configuration
public class ControlBus {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(controlChannel()).controlBus().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel controlChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }
}
```

With this, I'm able to start/stop the inbound from some integration flow, with:

```
controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@myInbound.start()"));
controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@myInbound.stop()"));
```

The `.send` method returns true or false depending on the message being sent or not.
How can I check the status of the bean?

```
controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("@myInbound.isRunning()"));
```

will also return true or false,

```
new MessagingTemplate().send(controlChannel, new GenericMessage<>("@myInbound.isRunning()"));
```

will just send the message and return nothing

```
new MessagingTemplate().sendAndReceive(controlChannel, new GenericMessage<>("@myInbound.isRunning()"));
```

sends the message and hangs waiting for a response.

How can I properly configure the output for the control bus and return it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as expected:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
public class So74741707Tests {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("controlBusFlow.input")
    MessageChannel controlBusFlowInput;

    @Test
    void receiveReplyFromControlBus() {
        MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();
        assertThat(
                messagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(this.controlBusFlowInput,
                        new GenericMessage<>("@myEndpoint.isRunning()")))
                .extracting(Message::getPayload)
                .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.BOOLEAN)
                .isFalse();

        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(this.controlBusFlowInput, "@myEndpoint.start()");

        assertThat(
                messagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(this.controlBusFlowInput,
                        new GenericMessage<>("@myEndpoint.isRunning()")))
                .extracting(Message::getPayload)
                .asInstanceOf(InstanceOfAssertFactories.BOOLEAN)
                .isTrue();
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    public static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow controlBusFlow() {
            return BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition::controlBus;
        }

        @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel", autoStartup = "false")
        @EndpointId("myEndpoint")
        public void myService(Object payload) {

        }

    }

}
```

Probably you more than just that Control Bus subscribers on your `controlChannel`.

The `start()` and `stop()` are really one-way operations. Therefore indeed just `send()` is enough. The `isRunning()` returns a `boolean` and to handle it we have to perform a request-reply operation or send the reply message to the output channel of that Control Bus endpoint.

Comment: All right, I'm not sure what I did wrong the first time... `sendAndReceive` indeed returns the message with the the result from `isRunning` as payload, as expected.